# Does finite-presentedness fail to be hereditary for modules over a Noetherian ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a left Noetherian ring.

It is a basic fact in algebra that any left-$R$-submodule of a finitely-generated left $R$-module is again finitely-generated.

I was wondering if the above fails for finite-presentedness?

I.e., is there a left $R$-module which is finitely-presented but admits a left $R$-submodule with no finite presentation (as a left $R$-module)?

---

Edit: as the answer points out, finite-presentedness follows from finite-generation, for left modules over a left Noetherian ring.

Comment: Yes, as I finished reading this the comment that came to mind is "for Noetherian rings, f.g. and f.p. are the same thing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any finitely generated left module $M$ over a left Noetherian ring $R$ is finitely presented. Take any epimorphism $R^n \twoheadrightarrow  M$. The kernel is a submodule of $R^n$ and hence finitely generated, as $R$ is Noetherian. Thus $M$ is finitely presented.

So if the base ring is left Noetherian, finitely generated and finitely presented are equivalent for left modules.

Thus in particular, submodules of finitely presented modules are finitely presented.